# Scala Slick In-Memory Database SQLite No Such Table

Tags: sqlite, scala, slick, in-memory-database

Using Scala 2.10.2 and Slick 2.1.0, I'm writing a wrapper for an SQLite database. For testing, I'd like the ability to create an in-memory database, populate it with my tables, insert some data, and then run test queries. A toy equivalent of my database is outlined in the following working code snippet:

```
import org.sqlite.JDBC
import scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.simple._

object MyDB
{
    def testMemory() : Unit = MyDB.withMemoryTestDatabase( test )

    def testFile() : Unit = MyDB.withFileTestDatabase( test )

    val test : ( MyDB ) => Unit =
    {
        ( mydb ) => mydb.database.withSession{ implicit session => {
            mydb.metadata.map( m => ( m.key, m.value ) ).insert( ( "foo", "bar" ) )
            assert( mydb.metadata( "foo" ) == "bar" )
        } }
    }

    def withMemoryTestDatabase( testFunction : ( MyDB ) => Unit ) : Unit =
    {
        val backend = new MyDB( Database.forURL( "jdbc:sqlite::memory:", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC" ) )

        runTest( backend, testFunction )
    }

    def withFileTestDatabase( testFunction : ( MyDB ) => Unit ) : Unit =
    {
        val backend = new MyDB( Database.forURL( "jdbc:sqlite:test.sqlite", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC" ) )

        runTest( backend, testFunction )

        val dbPath = new java.io.File( "test.sqlite" )
        dbPath.delete
    }

    def runTest( backend : MyDB, testFunction : ( MyDB ) => Unit ) : Unit =
    {
        backend.database.withSession{ implicit session => backend.metadata.ddl.create }

        testFunction( backend )
    }
}

class MyDB( val database : slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.backend.DatabaseDef )
{
     class Metadata( tag : Tag ) extends Table[(String,String)]( tag, "Metadata" )
     {
         def key =   column[String]( "key" )
         def value = column[String]( "value" )

         def * = ( key, value )
     }

     object metadata extends TableQuery( new Metadata( _ ) )
     {
         def apply( key : String ) : String = database.withSession { implicit session => this.map( m => ( m.key, m.value ) ).run.toMap.apply( key ) }
     }       
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that with that code, `MyDB.testFile()` runs perfectly. However, `MyDB.testMemory()` fails, saying that the Metadata table doesn't exist. The full error and traceback is here:

```
scala> MyDB.testFile

scala> MyDB.testMemory
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Metadata)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:152)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:190)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.preparedInsert(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:170)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.internalInsert(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:180)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.insert(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:175)
    at MyDB$$anonfun$testMemory$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MyDb.scala:9)
    at MyDB$$anonfun$testMemory$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MyDb.scala:8)
    at scala.slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.withSession(DatabaseComponent.scala:34)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$4.withSession(JdbcBackend.scala:61)
    at MyDB$$anonfun$testMemory$1.apply(MyDb.scala:8)
    at MyDB$$anonfun$testMemory$1.apply(MyDb.scala:8)
    at MyDB$.withMemoryTestDatabase(MyDb.scala:28)
    at MyDB$.testMemory(MyDb.scala:8)
    at .<init>(<console>:8)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:790)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:702)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:889)
    at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:23)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
    at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

N.B. the `:memory:` argument to the JDBC constructor seems to work; it certainly doesn't create a `:memory:` file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you're making more than one connection to the db then the data doesn't persist. See here: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html. You may need to add the incantation '?cache=shared' to the end of the jdbc uri.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but a URL of `jdbc:sqlite::memory:?cache=shared` creates a file called `:memory:?cache=shared`, so that's not quite right.

Comment: If you're using the xerial library for sqlite jdbc, this may help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xerial/gGeqCw3KzvU

Comment: @paulmdavies, connection URI must be `jdbc:sqlite:file::memory:?cache=shared`

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the connection open (this helps in H2, only speculating about SQLite):

```
def runTest( backend : MyDB, testFunction : ( MyDB ) => Unit ) : Unit =
{
    backend.database.withSession{ implicit session =>
      backend.metadata.ddl.create
      testFunction( backend )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've modified my code to work like this (I meant to do so in the first place). I then pass the `session` explicitly to `testFunction`, and use it explicitly on each database call in the test function. However, that still doesn't work. Debug printing confirms the creation and the testing is using the same session. I'm at a loss!

Comment: maybe setup a sample github project to show the effect

Answer (score 0):

Try this option here: [How should one configure Slick to persist tables between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091300/how-should-one-configure-slick-to-persist-tables-between-sessions)

TLDR version: Add ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" to the end of your DB url.